# Who is displaying the ContextMenu: the form or the notification icon?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu, notifyicon

I have the same `ContextMenu` assigned to a Form and to a NotifyIcon.

```
this.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu;
this.notifyIcon.ContextMenu = this.ContextMenu;
```

In the `Popup` event of the context menu I'm trying to find out who is displaying the context menu: the form (such as a right click on the form), or the notify icon (a right click on the notification icon):

```
private void ContextMenu_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.contextMenu.SourceControl.Name);
}
```

However, I always get the form as the source control, even if I right click on the notification icon.

I'm using C#, .NET Framework 4.6 and Windows Forms.

Comment: You may check the `sender` object. On my test project, its `SourceControl` is my form when I right click on the form, and `null` when I right click on the notify icon.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, a quickest way is to have a flag:

```
private bool fromIcon;

private void notifyIcon1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
      fromIcon = true;
   }
}

private void ContextMenu_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fromIcon.ToString());
    fromIcon = false;
}
```